# How to display the requested post only?

Tags: posts

I have created a custom theme and my front page is `index.php`. Moreover, I have couple of blog posts and I display them with a loop in this page, together with a link for each particular post. The problem is that whenever I click on this link, the browser loads the correct permalink, e.g. `http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/2016/04/20/title-of-clicked-post/`, but the content remains the same.

I use `is_front_page()` to determine whether I am loading the front page or a single post. When I click on a single post, how to display this post **only** and not all the others?

Comment: WordPress creates the default query on each page automatically based on the requested URL. I'll guess you are probably creating your own query and outputting those results instead of just running [the standard loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was indeed the case. You can write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress creates the default query on each page automatically based on the requested URL. Your template file should contain [the standard loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to output whatever the default query contains.

```
if( have_posts() ){
    while( have_posts() ){
        the_post();

        the_title();
        the_content();

    }
}
```